# Plink never completes a private key ssh connection, doesn't timeout, key isn't refused. Putty works fine

Tags: ssh, tunnel, plink

My ultimate goal is to use MyEnTunnel to set up a tunnel between a Windows server at location A, and a BSD machine at location B so that I can access a database server running at location B locally at A. (localhost:3054 ======> bsdmachine:3050) MyEnTunnel is essentially a Windows Service wrapper for plink.

We use a private key for ssh access at location B. PuttyGen was used to convert the private key into a .ppk file to be compatible with putty, plink, etc. Putty connects to the BSD machine using the .ppk with no problems whatsoever.

I copied the command line string MyEnTunnel is using to establish the connection, pasted it into a directory with the latest version of putty, plink, etc. (in case MyEnTunnel's plink.exe is outdated), and it still failed.

```
 plink.exe 192.168.0.233 -N -ssh -2 -P 916 -l "root" -C -i "keyfile.ppk" -L 3054:192.168.0.208:3050
```

The BSD machine has several jails running; 1.233 is the host, and accepts SSH connections. 1.208 is a jail with a server listening to 3050, and will not accept ssh connections.

I use tunnels so rarely, I always forget the proper order of things, and when I'm supposed to ur -R and -L, so I tried the 16 possibilities. ;-) I then started plink with the bare options:

```
 plink.exe 192.168.0.233 -N -ssh -2 -P 916 -l "root" -i "keyfile.ppk"
```

Putty, with these settings, connects without a hitch. Plink reports:
    Using username "root".
And proceeds to do nothing forever.

What am I doing wrong, and what would establish the tunnel with the local listening port 3054, and the target port 3050 at 192.168.0.208?

Comment: Well, as always: what do the log files on the server side say?

Answer (score 0):

You used the -N flag, this makes it run on the background. If you add the -v flag you can see all the activity of the forward/tunnel.